# Flutter TikTok video carousel

Tags: flutter, carousel, video-processing, flutter-animation

I need to build an app with videos sliding carousel like in TikTok or Instagram. Is anybody know the best way to implement it with automatically preaching to show the video as fast as possible?

Comment: You should provide us with an example, video or image of what you want to do.